# RESTful API: Connect to specific database based on URL/endpoint

Tags: database, rest

Let's say there are two databases `customer1` and `customer2`, and I want to use one codebase to access them i.e connect to a database based on the URL.

`www.example.com/customer1/dashboard` would connect to `customer1`.
`www.example.com/customer2/dashboard` would connect to `customer2`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Do I name the database the same as the URL parameter, and then pass that parameter to the connection bit, or is there a better way?

Comment: This is far too subjective, there are many ways of implementing a multi-tenant architecture, and the question of what's "best" really depends on the nature and detail of your application. Also, I'm not really seeing the relevance of the `rest` tag here.

Comment: @James I've tried to find an answer and I failed, which is why I'm asking it. Sure, it is rather vague, I just have to start somewhere. :) What would the different ways look like? Can you please give some short examples?